# Wrong result of 'ddot' from BLAS

Tags: c, lapack, blas

I am having trouble with a C/C++ program that uses the BLAS routine `ddot`.
I am running Linux and so far LAPACK routines worked without any problems.

I get a wrong result, no matter if I choose the type `int` for integer arguments of `ddot` or if I choose `ptrdiff_t`.

The Code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

extern "C" {
    extern int ddot_( int*, double* , int* , double* ,int*); 
    // OR extern int ddot_( ptrdiff_t*, double* , ptrdiff_t* , double* ,ptrdiff_t*);
}

int main() {
    int n=3; // OR ptrdiff_t  n=3;
    int inc=1; // OR ptrdiff_t inc=1;
    double result=0;

    double *x = (double*) calloc (n, sizeof (double));
    double *y = (double*) calloc (n, sizeof (double));

    result = ddot_(&n, x, &inc, y, &inc);
    cout<<result<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If I choose `n` and `inc` to be of type `int` everything compiles but I get the output that `result` is equal to `4`. Same effect with different number for `x` and `y`.

I tried to google my question and found out that the type of `n` and `inc` might cause wrong results and I should try `ptrdiff_t` or `mwSignedIndex`. 
I didn't manage to include `mwSignedIndex` in my program so far but if I choose `n` and `inc` to be of type `ptrdiff_t` and change the "extern C" part in the beginning I get `4`as a result aswell.

Am I missing something? Is my math wrong?
I appreciate any help or suggestions!

EDIT: in a former version of the question I didn't manage to properly use the `ptrdiff_t`. Nevertheless the wrong result is still there.

Comment: Why not `#include <cblas.h>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The strange thing in your code is `ddot_` being declared as `extern C int`, while it is actually a `double`-valued function. And its value is assigned to a `double` variable `result`. Those conversions are probably what is causing your issues (I am not entirely sure how did it compile and passed the `-Wall` compiler flag – I hope you are using one).

`n` and `inc` being `int`s should be fine, unless you are not doing something very specific with a specifically configured version of BLAS on a particular architecture.

Comment: Arrrg... now I feel a little embarrassed for such a stupid mistake. I copy&pasted that part and forgot to adjust it accordingly.
And yes, I used `-Wall` and some other flags but there we no warnings and everything compiled smoothly.

Thank you very very much for helping me again!

Comment: I am not too surprised (about smooth compilation), just a tiny bit concerned - as this mistake is not as stupid as you think. C/C++ allows us to shoot ourselves in the foot in million different ways. This was just a tiny scratch on a skin and not a dangerous clot deep inside the vein.

Comment: @Blablablu It's not the compiler's business: when you link to a library that exports `ddot_` with a different type (and it's a C function, so no name mangling like with C++), the compiler cannot do anything because it doesn't see what's inside the library, and the linker can't do anything because it doesn't know about types. So no warning. Explaining the value it "returns" is complicated: it assumes the `int` is returned in the `eax` register, but `ddot` returns a `double` in an `xmm` register, so it just reads whatever was in the `eax` register after `ddot`. (I think.)

Comment: @Kirill I guess I am relying on my static code analysis (not just compiler&linker) tools a lot now – and expect them to catch all those things. Unfortunately, that's not a reality.

Comment: @AntonMenshov I wouldn't expect anything to be able to catch this, as the function's *prototype* is wrong. The reason they are usually right is that the same header is used when compiling the library as when including it, so you couldn't miss an error that way.

Comment: One more observation, the OP may hit similar troubles using cdot() or zdot(). They return a complex-float (C) or complex-double (Z) by value. Although returning a C or Z value is commonplace in Fortran, it is quirkier in C/C++... I have had trouble on some platforms correctly collecting these return values across an extern "C" boundary. This is a rare case where I think it is less fuss to write cdot() and zdot() yourself, than to try to call the BLAS. Most other BLAS/LAPACK functions use C/Z out-parameters instead of return values, so this issue is thankfully rare (just pun using a void*).